# Ionic IOS build (provisioning profile creation bug)

Tags: ios, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to generate ios application for testing purpose. For this, I created the ios platform and open it in Xcode. From xcode general settings I choose `Automatically Manage Sigining` and choose `Team` as my Apple account.

Then I am getting the following Status error:

```
 Cannot create an iOS App Development provisioning profile for "id-name".
Your development team, "Account Name", does not support the Push Notifications capability.
```

Please suggest how can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your application need push notification service but you don't have the privilege to access push notification. there is two way to solve this problem

1. You must want to remove push notification plugin or API from your code

(Or)

2. You must want to purchase an Apple developer program

Comment: I removed the plugin from package.json and config.xml, removed node modules and removed ios platform created new platform but still i have same issue.

Comment: if you have developer program means the push notification service will automatically enabled or also we can able to enable in capabilities but without developer account we cannot do anything because i also had same issue one week before

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate the Push capability in **Xcode**.

in Xcode, go to `capabilities` tab, and enable push :

[image]

set `Remote notifications` in `Background Modes` :

[image]